# Protocol writes data into file even when the if statement should be passed

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, network-protocols

I wanted to do a protocol that efficiently writes a jpg file data from the server to a client by writing the given data to a file in the client's C:\ directory.

The protocol does it as the new jpg file is present and complete at the client's computer,

but the protocol keeps repeating itself and writing data into the file without ending,

leading it to have an enormous file size

and the protocol doesn't end so I the client can access the other protocols I have.

Can anyone notice what I am doing wrong?

***Server Protocol:***

```
if data == "screen shot":
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    im.save(r'C:\screen.jpg')
    file = open(r'C:\screen.jpg','rb').read()

    sizeoffile = os.stat(r'C:\screen.jpg').st_size
    client_socket.send(str(sizeoffile))
    if data == "Send file":
        client_socket.send(file)
```

**Client's Protocol:**

```
if x == "screen shot":
    print "Here you go"
    sizeof = my_socket.recv(1024)
    print "Size of file: " + str(sizeof)
    accumulated = bytes(0)
    doit = True
    file = open(r'C:\serverscreen.jpg','wb')
    my_socket.send("Send file")

    while doit:
        if accumulated < sizeof:
            print "Receiving..."
            my_socket.send("GOT IT")
            data = my_socket.recv(1024)
            accumulated = os.stat(r'C:\serverscreen.jpg').st_size # do a loop to check if accumulated equals sizeof to know if entire file has been, accumulated
            print "Accumulated: " + str(accumulated)
            file.write(data)
        else:
            doit = False

    file.close()
```

**Update**

**Client's Protocol:**

```
if x == "screen shot":
    print "Here you go"
    sizeof = int(my_socket.recv(1024))
    print "Size of file: " + str(sizeof)
    accumulated = bytes(0)
    doit = True
    file = open(r'C:\serverscreen.jpg','wb')
    my_socket.send("Send file")
    while doit:
        if accumulated < sizeof:
            print "Receiving..."
            my_socket.send("GOT IT")
            data = my_socket.recv(1024)#round(float(sizeof))))
            accumulated += struct.unpack('l',data) #os.stat(r'C:\serverscreen.jpg').st_size # do a loop to check if accumulated equels sizeof to know if entire file has been, accumulaed
            print "Accumulated: " + str(accumulated)
            file.write(data)
        else:
            doit = False

    file.close()
```

Comment: Hint: on the client side, `sizeof` is a string, not an integer.  For your next question, go read the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) documentation.

Comment: Ok thanks I looked into it, and made some changes, though now there's a weird problem where it just doesn't want to go into the doit loop at all... I'll update the post to show you, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's go through the issues here.

1. `sizeof = int(my_socket.recv(1024))`: You do not know that the number is exactly 1024 digits long.  Indeed, it is probably much shorter than that, so this is sucking up part of the image data.  You need to pack it into a fixed-width byte field with [`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) on the server side, then unpack it with the same format on the client side.
2. `accumulated = bytes(0)`: In Python 2.7, `bytes` is exactly synonymous with `str` (in 3.x it's still a string-like thing, but slightly different).  In other words, this is not an integer, it is a string.  If you had been using Python 3, this would have thrown an exception at the line `if accumulated < sizeof:`, since 3.x doesn't allow comparing integers to strings.
3. `my_socket.send("Send file")`/`my_socket.send("GOT IT")`: Since the server never calls `recv()`, this data could theoretically fill up the TCP buffer and block.  In practice it won't because you're only sending a small amount, but in general, you can't send things unless the other side is receiving them.
4. `accumulated += struct.unpack('l',data)`: That won't work.  You do in fact want `len(data)` here.

Comment: Fantastic ! :) I adjusted after I understood your points my code for both sides and now it does it and writes in just the right amount! only a little adjusting on the: ending the protocol so I can do the others effieciently

Comment: and it's done. Thanks again, you explained very well and left me stuff to figure out on my own which I really appreciate :) Thanks!